# Can't get extras in my BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, foreground

I've got a problem with implementing my service class. By logs everything works fine in service (extras are put and countdown is working and notification is shown after time is up). But i can't get extras, to update my views. The idea is to make my service running when app is even killed and update multiple timers in recycler view. 
Here is my code for that. Any information would be helpful

The part where i'm trying to register my service

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, TimerService.class);
        startServiceIntent.putExtra(EXTRAS_TIME, timeCountInMilliSeconds);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
        Log.d("Service", "startService");

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra(EXTRAS_COUNTDOWN, 0L);

                Log.d("Service", "Smthisreceived");

                task.timeLeft = String.valueOf(timeLeft); // here add left time for timer

                textViewTimeCV.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(millisUntilFinished)); // just handling status bar values

                progressBarCV.setProgress((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }
        };

        context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.category.DEFAULT"));
        Log.d("Service", "receiverRegistered");
```

Service

```
public class TimerService extends Service {

private CountDownTimer ctd;
private Intent broadcastIntent;
private int requestCode;
private long timeCountInMillis;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("In service", "+1");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    requestCode =  (int)(intent.getLongExtra(EXTRAS_TIME, 0L));

    timeCountInMillis = intent.getLongExtra(EXTRAS_TIME, 0L);

    broadcastIntent = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BROADCAST_RECEIVER);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getTextFromResource(this, R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(getTextFromResource(this, R.string.your_timer) + " "
                    + getTextFromResource(this, R.string.is_currently_running))
            .setSmallIcon(ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    startForeground(requestCode, notification.build());

    ctd = new CountDownTimer(timeCountInMillis , 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            broadcastIntent.putExtra(EXTRAS_COUNTDOWN, millisUntilFinished);
            Log.d("Extras_are_put", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            stopForeground(true);

        }
    }.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}}
```

My constants

```
public static final String COUNTDOWN_BROADCAST_RECEIVER = "com.example.hp.intimer.TimerService";
public static final String EXTRAS_COUNTDOWN = "Countdown";
public static final String EXTRAS_TIME = "Time";
```

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `sendBroadcast()` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve my problem:(still no extras

Comment: You're registering the Receiver with the wrong action. Your broadcast `Intent` is using `COUNTDOWN_BROADCAST_RECEIVER`, but you've got `"android.intent.category.DEFAULT"` on the `IntentFilter`. Also, "no extras" is kinda misleading, isn't it? I mean, your Receiver isn't running at all, is it?

Comment: About wrong action, i saw it today in morning and fixed by myself. And, you saved my day about sendBroadcast(). Your first comment is correct answer

Comment: Hey, after i fixed bug with receiver i&amp;#39;ve got another one now. All this construction is in recycler view, controls multiple timers. New issue is timers are flickering now. I will create new question tomorrow, please check it if you might have any ideas about why it works in such way and how to fix it